# Copy from CV_8UC4 to CV_8UC3 using alpha channel

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a small rendered image with alpha channel as `GpuMat` with type `CV_8UC4`. I have many `GpuMat` instances with 3 channels as `CV_8UC3`. I want to blit this RGBA to every other image's top left corner respecting the aplha channel correctly.

```
GpuMat icon = renderLogoWithTransparency(); // CV_8UC4
std::vector<GpuMat> &images = imageLibrary();  // CV_8UC3
for(auto &image: images)
{
  Rect target(0,0,icon.cols,icon.rows);
  icon.copyTo(image(target));
}
```

The resulting error is: `OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (!fixedType() || ((cuda::GpuMat*)obj)->type() == mtype) in create, file /root/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 2260`

Which seems rightful as `copyTo` is for simple copying and I want color blending. How can I do the blending without downloading from GPU to main memory?

Comment: Sounds more like you want to do blending, not just copy the contents to given location (which would assume the types match).

Comment: Yes. I want blending. Editing the question for clarity.

Comment: `split`+`merge` to get RGB and alpha components of icon -- let's call those `Sc` and `Sa` respectively, and let's call destination `Dc`. Convert `Sa` to float, and scale to range [0-1]. Let `Da = 1 - Sa`. Now `Dc * Da + Sc * Sa` does the blend (per element operations). AFAICT there are GPU variants of all those functions.

Comment: per-pixel "weighted add" is not part of openCV but you probably can code that simple gpu kernel yourself.